# On Demand Container Serving With GCP

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a Docker image that will execute different logic depending on the environment variables that it is run with. You can imagine that running it with `VAR=A` will produce slightly different logic compared to running it with `VAR=B`.

We have an application that is meant to allow users to kick off tasks that are defined within this Docker image. Depending on the user attributes, different environment variables will need to be passed into the Docker container when it is run. The task is meant to run each time an event is generated through user action and then the container should shut down/be removed.

I'm trying to determine if GCP has any container services that best match what I'm looking for. My understanding of some of the services is:

- Cloud Functions - can work well for consuming events and taking specific actions each time an event is triggered, but it is not suited for containerized workloads.
- Cloud Run - a serverless way of deploying containers. As I understand it, a deployment on cloud run spins up a "service", and the environment variables must be passed in as part of the service definition. Because we may have a large number of combinations of environment variables (many of which may need to be running at once), it seems that this would end up creating a large number of services, which feels potentially clunky. This approach seems better for deploying a single service with static environment variables that needs to be auto-scaled by GCP.
- GKE - another container orchestration platform. This is what I'm considering at the moment. The idea is that we would define a single job definition that can vary according to environment variables that are passed into it. The problem is that these jobs would need to be kicked off dynamically via code. This is a fairly straightforward process with `kubectl`, but the Kubernetes REST API seems fairly underdeveloped (or at least not that well documented). And the lack of information online on how to start jobs on-demand through the Kubernetes API makes me question whether this is the best approach.

Are there any tools that I'm missing that would be useful in spinning up containers on-demand with dynamic sets of environment variables and removing them when done?

Comment: Your assessment is accurate. Cloud Run is oriented towards the deployment of servers that listen on TCP socket (port 8080) rather than "jobs". GKE would be better suited to the deployment of large numbers of short-lived tasks. Stack overflow is focused on programming (rather than architectural) questions and so your question may get dinged for being off-topic.

Comment: In your perspective, how do you plan/want to call your container service with environment variables? Perform an API call (a POST or a GET for example)?

Comment: For what you're describing I might set up a job queue like RabbitMQ, and instead of trying to dynamically launch containers, have long-running worker containers that pull tasks off the queue and execute them.  The variables could be provided as part of the task description.  This avoids the complexities of dynamically starting and managing containers, and you could run the same setup locally or on GCP (or on another public cloud).

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Yes, I was planning on performing an API call that contains the relevant environment variables as parameters. And these variables would be passed into the container when it is launched.

Comment: Does your container serve HTTP requests?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Unfortunately it does not. It spawns a fairly heavy Python process in the background, but it would not be particularly straightforward to change to expose this functionality as API endpoints.

Comment: If you don't serve HTTP traffic, that limit greatly your options!! Only GKE is an option. If you want to use Cloud Run, you must add a webserver in front of your container. The webserver get the param from the request, add them to the environment variable, and then trigger the container entrypoint (the python file) to run. At the end of the run, the webserver get the result and send it back to the requester. It's not so difficult to code